# ISO 3661-2 Region Codes

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api, google

I have noticed that Google Maps API provide the ISO code as the short name for the country. However for regions it is quite variable...
For instance if I want to check Madrid, Spain:

```
ISO-Code Spain: ES
ISO-Code Region of Madrid: MD (Google does not provide this one)
ISO-Code City of Madrid: M
```

And this is just an example. For Germany it does not return the ISO Codes for the cities.

How can we parse the location with our private database? Does the Google Maps API follow any standard for the codes?

Answer (score 1):

ISO 3661-2 doesn't often apply to cities; Madrid is an exception.

The ISO code for [Madrid the Autonomous community](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Community_of_Madrid) is `ES-MD` not just `MD` and the ISO code for Madrid the Province is `ES-M` not just `M`.

There are no cities defined for Germany under ISO 3661-2, only the [16 states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2:DE)

The Google API would therefore seem to be based on ISO 3661-2, except it seems to cut off the two letter country code.